# JQuery UI Tooltip how to set custom tip position "of" clicked element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to create the QA section with tips appearing against the question mark by clicking on it. By now I get it work by click.

Now I need to make it positioned against clicked element. I understand that I need to use Of Position property, but not able to make it work for more than one clicked item.

Please help!

Here is the latest code:

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/manicko/vScw2/5/)

And in regards to this forum rules here is my html:

```
<--! tip 1-->
<span id="thelp-1" class="helper hidden"></span>
<div class="center" >here will be text  1</div>
<a href="#" id="help-1"  class="help">?</a>         
    <div id="txthelp-1" class="hidden">
       <div class="helpContent">
         Tip text 1
          </div>
     </div>

<--! tip 2-->    
<span id="thelp-2" class="helper hidden"></span>
<div class="center">here will be text  1</div>
<a href="#" id="help-2"  class="help">?</a>         
      <div id="txthelp-2" class="hidden">
         <div class="helpContent">
             Tip text 2
         </div>
      </div>
```

And  js code:

```
    $(function() {
        $( ".helper" ).tooltip({
             items: '.helper',
              content: function() {
               var text= $(this).attr('id');
                return $( "#tx"+text).html();
            },
            position: {
                my: "center bottom-15",
                at: "center  top",
                //of: "#help-1",
                using: function( position, feedback ) {                    

                    $(this).css( position );  
                    $( "<div>" )
                            .addClass( "arrow" )
                            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                            .appendTo( this );
                }
             }

        });

        $( ".help" ).on( 'click', function() {
          var tip=  $(this).attr('id');
            if(!$(this).hasClass('opened')) {
             $( "#t"+tip ).tooltip( 'open' );                
             $(this).addClass('opened');               
        } else {
          $( "#t"+tip ).tooltip( 'close' );
            $(this).removeClass('opened');
        }                      
        });

    });
```

By clicking on "a with id help" Tooltip opens against the hidden "span with id thelp". 
What i need is to make it appear against each  "a" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set tooltip position in the click handler function:

```
$(".help").on('click', function () {
    var tip = $(this).attr('id');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('opened')) {
        $("#t" + tip).tooltip("option", "position", {
            my: "center bottom-15",
            at: "center  top",
            of: $(this),
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        });
        $("#t" + tip).tooltip('open');
        $(this).addClass('opened');
    } else {
        $("#t" + tip).tooltip('close');
        $(this).removeClass('opened');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VqQ8b/

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've spend a day on it, sorry for not able to vote for your answer((